# Pass a func as a background-image url parameter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can I pass a function into a background-image url parameter in jQuery?

Something like this...

```
jQuery('<span>').css('background-image', 'url(' + check_file_type(value.Name) + ')');
```

The function returns the url address in it's proper format, I assume I'm just not calling it right.

```
    function get_extension(filename) {
        return filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    }

    function check_file_type(file) { 
        switch(get_extension(file)) {
            //if .jpg/.gif/.png do something
            case 'jpg': case 'gif': case 'png':
                return '{!URLFOR($Resource.images, 'images/doctype_image.png')}';
                break;
            //if .zip/.rar do something else
            case 'zip': case 'rar':
                return '{!URLFOR($Resource.images, 'images/doctype_zip.png')}';
                break;

            //if .pdf do something else
            case 'pdf': case 'pptx':
                return '{!URLFOR($Resource.images, 'images/doctype_pdf.png')}';
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: basically that's possible ... post that function please

Comment: Try doing `console.log(check_file_type(value.Name))` and `console.log('url(' + check_file_type(value.Name) + ')')` to make sure the result is what you expect.

Comment: `jQuery('<span>')` creates a new `span`. Is that what you're trying to do, or are you trying to select an existing element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.
The function should return a string and your good.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. The function should return a string.
I also see that the Jquery you're calling creates a new  element. Is this what you want to achieve? For my example, I just assumed an existing span element.

```
function init() {                    
    var value = {};
    value.name = "Hello";

    $('span').css('background-image', 'url(' + check_file_type(value.name) + ')');
}

function check_file_type(name) {
    return "http://" + name + ".jpg";
}

init();
```

A small [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fau3M/) as a working example. Note that the check_file_type function in my example is not really checking any file types.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue myself, was down to an extra curly bracket...